# How to send email using Magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created a form with some input fields in Magento. But when I click submit, Magento will not send the email.

How can I send a basic email in Magento?

Comment: Should I need to create a separate module in app/code/local/ directory.

Comment: Why is not being a native English speaker and writing elaborate tutorials with ridiculous typos prerequisites for mastery of Magento???

Comment: No @SpencerWilliams "It has tow reason"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

simple function to send the email in magento

```
<?php
    public function sendMailAction() 
    {
        $html="
        put your html content here
        blah blah

        ";
        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName('Your Name');
        $mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');
        $mail->setBody('Mail Text / Mail Content');
        $mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
        $mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
        $mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
        $mail->setType('html');// You can use Html or text as Mail format
        $mail->setBodyHTML($html);  // your content or message

        try {
            $mail->send();
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
            $this->_redirect('');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
            $this->_redirect('');
        }
    }
?>
```

[Reference](http://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento/magento-send-email-programmatically/)

Comment: In which directory should I need to place the above code.Can you please suggest me.

Comment: you can add in your controller file ,helper or block where you want it..

Comment: I had not created any helper or model,Then how can I use it.Please explain

Comment: then add this function in your phtml file and send mail from there..

Comment: Can I use variable as $mail->setToName($name).Is it works.

Comment: yes it will work..

Comment: I need to send the form details as testname,city,location.How to set in body.Please suggest me

Comment: add in your $html variable..

Comment: Actually I had created my form in other phtml file.Then How to print those filled details in body.

Comment: this is another question :D are you submit the form? 
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('fieldname');

Comment: when I click on the submit button it should send the mail to the required customer

Comment: yes it will work like that if all code are correct

Comment: Ok.How to save this data in database.

Comment: have your created any table for that?

Comment: No,I have not created the table actually this is creating for when the tests are not found.I should send the email to the customers to book.

Comment: Already I have a Order table.I need to get this data to Order table

Comment: did you have the order id?

Comment: Yes.I have the Order Id

Comment: Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999); if you have order id

Comment: In the same file should i need to write the code.

Comment: yes you can do that..

Comment: Ok.If i had any doubts.I will ping you

Comment: Hey it is not showing any message it is redirecting to new page.Please help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29929/discussion-between-mouni-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: Hey I could not get the testname in the mail.It is printing only the TestName: but not variable

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add multiple mail addresses in the code for setfrom

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: I need to send for two mail ids.How to add another mail id in code

Comment: $mail->addBcc("some@email.com"); you can add like that

Comment: @QaisarSatti: Hi bro your code working fine. And i want to add Bcc, i tried this code `$mail->addBcc("test@domain.com");` but i got error like this https://ibb.co/h5gE46

Comment: @RameshS    try `$mail->addHeader('Bcc', 'test@domain.com');`

Comment: @QaisarSatti: Thanks for reply bro again showing error `Invalid method Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email::addHeader`.

Comment: @RameshS disabled the smtppro then check it is showing the same error?

Comment: @RameshS try `$mail->setBcc('Youe Email');`

Comment: Bro no error showing now but `mail` not send for `Bcc`

Comment: @RameshS this is final opt `$mail->getMail()->addBcc(''test@test.com);`  or check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126899/how-to-add-cc-or-bcc-in-custom-email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71514/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 5):

Create New Template Form "Transactional Emails".

```
hello {{var customerName}},
  You received test template. 
Thank you
```

After create New Template Note Its **ID**

Create controller action

```
public function sendEnquiry()
{
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

$templateId = 8; // Enter you new template ID
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');  //Get Sender Name from Store Email Addresses
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');  //Get Sender Email Id from Store Email Addresses
$sender = array('name' => $senderName,
            'email' => $senderEmail);

// Set recepient information
$recepientEmail = $customer->getEmail();
$recepientName = $customer->getName();      

// Get Store ID     
$store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

// Set variables that can be used in email template
$vars = array('customerName' => $customer->getName());  


// Send Transactional Email
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
    ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);

Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('We Will Contact You Very Soon.'));
}
```

Now You can send simple mail using Admin "Transactional Emails".

Following Your your_form.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("your_module_name/index/sendEnquiry")?>" id="discuss" method="post">

//Your form 

</form>
```

Comment: In which directory I need to save the controller file

Comment: you can save controller in your your_module/controller/IndexController.php create class and its relevant function.

Comment: Should I need to create any model or helper.Please suggest me I am new to magento

Comment: you can add/create new function in any module controller file

Comment: What function I need to add

Comment: you can check my code which is updated as per your requirement..

Comment: It looks like sendTransactional() ignores the {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}} from the email template??

Answer (score 2):

Try this code and adjust it accordingly

```
$email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
    ->loadDefault($template_id);

/* load template by id */
$email_template_variables = array(
    'customer_name' => $customer_name);

$sender_email = 'Info@yourCompany.com';
$sender_name =  'Your Friend at The Company';                          
$email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
$email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 

$email_template->send(
    $email_to, $customer_name,$email_template_variables
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For UTF-8 mail:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
$mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $senderName);
$mail->addTo($toEmail, $toName);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBodyHTML($html); // Or plain: $mail->setBodyText($text)
$mail->send();
```

Comment: this is for Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Basic (should work in a separate php script). It worked without exceptions, but I did not receive mail. So I spent more time on setting the SMTP.

```
// do not forget to include Mage.php before that
Mage::app();
// send email
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
 ->setToEmail('<my email>')
 ->setBody('Body')
 ->setSubject('Subject:'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
 ->setFromEmail('<from email>')
 ->setFromName('Magento Store Admin')
 ->setType('html');

$mail->send();
```

Prerequisites:

1. The Magento mail settings set to localhost (**System -> Configuration -> System -> Mail Sending Settings**)
2. Make sure that your SMTP working (on localhost you can check, you might need to install telnet "yum install telnet" on CentOS)

   ```
   telnet localhost 25
   MAIL FROM: <put from mail>
   RCPT TO: <put to mail>
   data: 
   Subject: <put your subject>
   <Put body here>
   . 
   QUIT
   ```
3. If it's not working configure SMTP. There was postfix running on my CentOS

   ```
    ps aux | grep posfix
   ```

I edited the settings with vi:

```
     vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

setting just myhostname worked for me

4. Try php mail function:

   ```
   // The message
   $message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
   // Send
   $headers = 'From: <from mail>' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: <from mail>' . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
   mail('<to mail>', 'My Subject', $message, $headers);    
   echo "<p>php mail sent 3</p>";
   ```
5. For postfix you can view the mail queue typing "mailq"