# How to add cc or bcc in custom email

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I have created a transactional email template and sending mail using below code :

```
$to_user_email = 'test@gmail.com';
$to_user = 'test';

$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('My Template');
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');     
$sender = array('name' => $senderName,
            'email' => $senderEmail);
$store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

// Set variables that can be used in email template
$vars = array();
$vars['order_id'] = 'order_id';
$vars['content'] = 'content';

$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($vars);

$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
     ->setToName($to_user)
     ->setToEmail($to_user_email)
     ->setBody($processedTemplate)
     ->setSubject('Subject')
     ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
     ->setFromName($senderName)
     ->setType('TEXT')
     ->setCc(array('test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com'));
$mail->send();
```

From above code email sent to `$to_user_email` but cc not sent to `'test1@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com'`.

How to send cc or bcc to multiple email address?

Comment: How to configure mail in magento

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below code:

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$mail->getMail()->addCc('zzz@gmail.com');
$mail->addBcc('zzz@gmail.com')
    ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId))
    ->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)
    ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $useremail, $emailName, $vars, $storeId);
```

Comment: Hello @Prashant Valanda, where you set `My Template` transactional email template?

Comment: Instead of `$templateId` you need to pass your template

Comment: I have tried this code but no email sent to `$useremail` and also not sent to cc/bcc email address.

Comment: nice to hear it is working for you.If it helps you mark as accepted for further use.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code

```
                $storeId=Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                $emailTemplateId='Youe email temlate';
                //Multiple BCC email address
                $add_bcc=array("someone@domain.com","someone2@domain.com");
                //Multiple CC email address
                $add_cc=array("someone3@domain.com","someone4@domain.com");
                $email='useremail@domain.com';
                $sender = Array('name' => 'test','email' => 'test@domain.com');
                $mailSubject='Your subject';
                $vars = Array('name' => 'Your message');

                $translate=Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                $translate->getMail()->addCc($add_cc);
                $translate->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)
                    ->addBCC($add_bcc)
                    ->sendTransactional($emailTemplateId, $sender, $email, null, $vars, $storeId);
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```