# Custom Form with not sending emails from frontend:Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from Contact Us Form

Tags: magento-1.9, error, email, forms

I have following email controller in my custom module not sending emails. when I print the **$params** arrays it giving the output not email is not sending. Please check and let me know what is wrong with this

```
public function sendemailAction()
{       $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); 
        print_r($params);

        $body = '<h3>Contact Form</h3><p>Hello,</p>
        <p>We have received this message from the website:</p>
        <p><b>Name:</b> ' . ($params['name']) . '<br>
        <p><b>Email:</b> ' . ($params['email']) . '<br>
        <b>Comments:</b> ' . ($params['comment']) . '</p>';         
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();        
        $mail->setBodyHtml($body);        
        $mail->setFrom($params['email'], $params['name']);        
        $mail->addTo('test@test.com');        
        $mail->setSubject('Contact Form');        

        try {            

            $mail->send(); 

        }        

            catch(Exception $ex) 

        {           
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from Contact Us Form.');         

        }           $this->_redirect('reviews/');

    }
```

Comment: check this  answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85373/how-to-send-email-using-magento

Comment: Invalid method Mage_Core_Model_Email::addTo(Array
(
[0] => tests@techleadz.com
)
@QaisarSatti

Comment: Changed addTo with setToEmail still the error unable to send

Comment: did you check other email is working eg: forgot password, create account etc

Comment: Actually its not sending as i am on local server like(Xamp) may be that cause the issue? @QaisarSatti

Comment: yes local server causing the issue

Comment: Yes it was just due to the local server, i have moved the work on live domain its working fine.